# how do I use the substing to return the set variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I run them its telling me:  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
But I need to pass this to the remaining script
--These values are used to search
--This is the only block modify who needed some polishing

```
 BEGIN

DECLARE @ResultsTable TABLE (ColumnName nvarchar(200), ColumnValue nvarchar(100))

DECLARE @ColumnName nvarchar(128), 
        @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110),
        @TableName nvarchar(256), 
        @TableName2 nvarchar(256)

DECLARE @PolicyPrefix nvarchar(5), 
        @PolicyID nvarchar(10), 
        @PolicyEffDate date, 
        @Policy nvarchar(10),  --needless ,
SET @TableName = ' '

SET @PolicyPrefix = SELECT SUBSTRING(Policy, 1, 5) 
                    FROM [dbo].[DWXP050] 
                WHERE intcov LIKE '%epl%' --'CMPMO' ------notices it only the policy letter part from the search result

SET @PolicyID = SELECT SUBSTRING(Policy,6,len(Policy)-5) 
                FROM [dbo].[DWXP050] 
             WHERE intcov LIKE '%epl%'  ---'08929' ------notices it only the policy number part from the search result

SET @PolicyEffDate = SELECT cast(cast(EFFDTE as varchar)as date) 
                     FROM [dbo].[DWXP050] 
                 WHERE intcov LIKE '%epl%' ----'2009-11-01' ------notices it has dashes from the search result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT @PolicyPrefix = SUBSTRING(Policy, 1, 5) FROM [dbo].[DWXP050] WHERE intcov LIKE '%epl%' --'CMPMO' ------notices it only the policy letter part from the search result

SELECT @PolicyID = SUBSTRING(Policy, 6) FROM [dbo].[DWXP050] WHERE intcov LIKE '%epl%'---'08929' ------notices it only the policy number part from the search result

SELECT @PolicyEffDate = cast(cast(EFFDTE as varchar)as date) FROM [dbo].[DWXP050] WHERE intcov LIKE '%epl%' ----'2009-11-01' ------notices it has dashes from the search result
```

Comment: I would also add `TOP 1` since it is being selected from a table , incase of multiple values are returned the query doesn't error out.

Comment: its saying:
Must declare the scalar variable "@PolicyPrefix".   
Must declare the scalar variable "@PolicyEffDate".
Must declare the scalar variable "@PolicyPrefix".

Comment: Yes, you need to declare your variables.  I'm assuming that's done in whatever procedure your pulled this from.  The code sample here just fixes the snippet you posted here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @PolicyID = SELECT SUBSTRING(Policy, 6) FROM [dbo].[DWXP050] WHERE intcov LIKE '%epl%'---'08929' ------notices it only the policy number part from the search result
```

You have not added third parameter for the substring function in this line. Add it

Comment: because i want it to start at the 6 th character till the end of the string  
look at the explample here. http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-substring.html

Answer (score 0):

put select statement in () like-

```
SET @PolicyPrefix = (SELECT SUBSTRING(Policy, 1, 5) FROM [dbo].[DWXP050] WHERE intcov LIKE '%epl%')
```

and after @policy nvarchar(10) you have Needless (,)

Comment: because i want it to start at the 6 th character till the end of the string  
look at the explample here. http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-substring.html

Answer (score 0):

'/these are the changes I have made and this is the answer that has work for me. Thanks Everyone./'

```
  BEGIN

    DECLARE @ResultsTable TABLE ( ColumnName  nvarchar(200)
    ,                             ColumnValue nvarchar(100) )

    DECLARE @ColumnName nvarchar(128)
    ,       @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
    ,       @TableName  nvarchar(256)
    ,       @TableName2 nvarchar(256)

    DECLARE @PolicyPrefix  nvarchar(5)
    ,       @PolicyID      nvarchar(10)
    ,       @PolicyEffDate date
    ,       @Policy        nvarchar(13)

    --SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

    SET @TableName = ' '

    --These values are used to search

    SET @PolicyPrefix = (SELECT TOP 1 SUBSTRING(Policy, 1, 5)
    FROM [dbo].[DWXP050]
    WHERE intcov LIKE '%epl%') --'CMPMO' ------notices it only the policy letter part from the search result

    SET @PolicyID = (SELECT TOP 1 SUBSTRING(Policy,6,len(Policy)-5)
    FROM [dbo].[DWXP050]
    WHERE intcov LIKE '%epl%')---'08929' ------notices it only the policy number part from the search result

    SET @PolicyEffDate = (SELECT TOP 1 cast(cast(EFFDTE as varchar)as date)
    FROM [dbo].[DWXP050]
    WHERE intcov LIKE '%epl%') ----'2009-11-01' ------notices it has dashes from the search result

    SET @SearchStr2 = (SELECT [SystemAssignId]
    FROM dbo.[CoPolicyPointer]

    WHERE [PolicyPrefixCd] = @PolicyPrefix

        AND [PolicyId] = @PolicyID

        AND [PolicyEffDt] = @PolicyEffDate)

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN

        SET @ColumnName = QUOTENAME('SystemAssignId')

        SET @TableName = (

        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))

        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

        WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

            AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName

        )

        SET @TableName2 = 'dbo.' + @TableName

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO @ResultsTable

            EXEC(

            'SELECT ''' + @TableName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 100)

FROM ' + @TableName2 + ' (NOLOCK) ' +

            ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ''' + @SearchStr2 + ''''

            )

        END

    END

    SELECT DISTINCT ColumnName
    ,               ColumnValue
    FROM @ResultsTable

END
```